# Console.WriteLine from with the Nuget Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

If I type the following code into a typical PS window, I am able to correctly get "asdf" in the output:

```
[System.Console]::WriteLine("asdf")
```

But if I do it in the NuGet Package Manager Console nothing is output.  Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Because NPM is not a console app.  It is hosted inside Visual Studio and implements the PowerShell host interfaces to allow the PowerShell engine to display output to what is likely a WPF window.

To get output in NPM use:

```
Write-Host "asdf"
```

or simply

```
"asdf"
```

If not in a cmdlet, you can do something like this:

```
private void WriteHost(string message)
{
    var runspace = Runspace.DefaultRunspace;
    var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline("Write-Host '" + message + "'", false);
    pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Is your C# code a cmdlet?  If so, then yes, just use this.WriteOutput().

Comment: No, it's not a cmdlet.  We have a whole bunch of logic that we don't want to convert to powershell, but we could change all the calls to Console.WriteLine to something else if that meant it would output in PS.  Is it possible to do this?